# How to get output of particular text from text file using batch?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

**I have a text file named `file.txt` it contains,**

```
---------- 123.TXT: 20
```

I like to get only that `20` in output..

**for that i am running a below command,**

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=3" %%i in (file.txt) do (echo %%i)
pause>nul
```

**expected output,**

```
20
```

**the output which am getting,**

```
.TXT: 20
```

**Note :** That value 20 will be change in different text files. Its not a stable value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the options of [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

- `tokens` defines the position(s) of the token(s) to extract (default: `1`, meaning first token);
- `delims` defines a set of characters that separate the tokens (default: <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and <kbd>TAB</kbd>);

So you need to use the following code:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=3" %%I in (file.txt) do echo %%I
```

If the file name (`123.txt`) might contain <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> on its own, change the code to:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%J in (file.txt) do for /F %%I in (file.txt) do echo %%I
```

---

The content of `file.txt` seems to be the output of the command [`find /C`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html). You can avoid the prefix (`---------- 123.TXT:` ) by changing the command line:

```cmd
find /C [/I] [/V] "<string>" 123.txt > file.txt
```

to:

```cmd
find /C [/I] [/V] "<string>" < 123.txt > file.txt
```

Then you do not need to split it off later:

```cmd
for /F %%I in (file.txt) do echo %%I
```

Of course you do not need to use an interim file:

```cmd
for /F %%I in ('find /C [/I] [/V] "<string>" ^< 123.txt') do echo %%I
```

Comment: Awesome. Am Impressed.. That really helps me a lot bro. You fixed my code which i asked and also understood what am doing and made my code much easier. And also teach me in easy understandable way. I understood what i made mistake and how much easy i can make it without double codes and with single one. Heartly Thanks a lot. Thumbs up ❤️